# AJAX 500 Server error after Merge MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

On an earlier build this worked, but in the merge process, my controller was swapped with a previous one that did not have the method I needed, so I just rewrote it. I don't know why, but now it is throwing an error:

> GET http://localhost:3602/TimeEntry/getPartial?_=1423251761474 500 (Internal Server Error)

The controller I'm calling is written like this:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult getPartial()
{
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name);
    ViewBag.user = user;

    //grab all the time entries for the user
    List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries = db.TimeEntries.Where(x => x.UserId == user.ID).OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeIn).ToList();
    ViewBag.TimeEntries = TimeEntries;

    //for the display name, put the full name together
    string cFullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
    ViewBag.fullName = cFullName;

    return PartialView(TimeEntries);
}
```

And my query:

```
function partial() {
        var table = $("#timesTable");
        console.log("hit after var table");
        var ajaxHandler = $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: '/TimeEntry/getPartial',
            cache: false
        });
        ajaxHandler.done(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            table.html(result);
        });
        ajaxHandler.fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError);
            console.log(xhr);
            alert('Fail');
        });
    }
```

The query is called on page load and on certain button clicks.

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: Well, I feel really silly now, but I had another visual studio open and upon closing both and reopening the project everything worked fine -_- I'm super sorry for it being such a simple fix

Comment: Since this question is of no use to anyone else, you should delete it.